# SVN repo migration from server to another server

Tags: windows, svn, migration, server, svnserve

I tried to migrated my repo without success. My original repository is on an old Windows server and the new server is a Windows server (2012).

Steps I follow:

1/ On the old server, I create a dump.

```
svnadmin dump PathtoMyOldRepo > MyOldRepo.svn_dump
```

Here, I see all revision diplayed like

```
 * Revision 0 déchargée.
 * Révision 1 déchargée.
 * Rév...
```

All look ok

2/ I created a Repo on the new server with the follow command line:

```
svnadmin create --fs-type=bdb \NewRepoName
```

All look ok

3/ I tried to dump the old repo to the new repo and here, nothing work! Following command lines don't work:

```
svnadmin load /MyNewRepoName < //MyOldRepoPath
```

Here I've got an error message:

```
L'opérateur « < » est réservé à une utilisation futures
```

Traduction: Operator « < » is reserved to futur application

So, I tried to replacer the `<` with `|` or `cat` without success.

The command line  `svnadmin load /MyNewRepoName cat //MyOldRepoPath` generated nothing. I press enter and the following message appear : `Ent^te de fichier de sauvegarde malform'e` traduction `File Header malformed`

Like you can see, I'n not very familiar with command lines and if you have a solution, I'll be very happy.

Comment: Why do you create BDB repository?

Comment: Good question. I just copy a command line without understand selected option. So, I re-created an another Repo with just `svnadmin create /NameOfNewRepo` and try the load comand without success...

Answer (score 1):

1. Try describe problem more accurately.

You dump data to file MyOldRepo.svn_dump and then what with this file? Nothing?

Then you try load data from misterious MyOldRepoPath. What is this?

And error subversion messages usually prefrixed with E*number*. It is valuable information.

2. Use full paths

   ```
   PC1:
   svnadmin dump c:\PathtoMyOldRepo > c:\MyOldRepo.svn_dump
   PC2:
   svnadmin load c:\PathtoMyNewRepo < c:\MyOldRepo.svn_dump
   ```

Comment: Sergey, I re-dump on my PC1 with the complete path and I can see the .svn_dump file into my old repo. But I do the same with PC2 and entire path but the error message is always the same. My command line :

Comment: So, now you should copy c:\MyOldRepo.svn_dump to PC2 as c:\MyOldRepo.svn_dump ands run second command. Does it works ?

Comment: My command line : `svnadmin load /E:/ProjectSVN < //192.168.1.151/D:/AppRepositories/MyProject` where E:/ProjectSVN is the new repo on the new server (PC2) and 192.168.1.151 the IP adress of the old server (PC1) where my old repo is located. The error message is: `Au caractère Ligne:1 : 30
+ svnadmin load /E:/ProjectSVN < //192.168.1.151/D:/AppRepositories/MyProject
+                              ~
L'opérateur « < » est réservé à une utilisation future.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RedirectionNotSupported`

Comment: If I can translate, the error message is something like : `at the character line:1 30 + svnadmin load /E:/ProjectSVN < //192.168.1.151/D:/AppRepositories/MyProject + ~ Operator  « < » is reserved to a futur operation`

Comment: I try to copy the .svn_dump on the PC2 and run the second command line but the same error message is displayed

Comment: 1. Try execute both commands in cmd.exe. Powershell can provide unwanted 'help'

2. You try to load AppRepositories/MyProject. Is it dump file? Look like repository directory. Use .dump extension for all dump files for sake of clarity

Comment: Yes, it work with cmd.exe! But I can't checkout the new repo created before with the svnadmin create command line. When I look into the new server, there is no SVN icon over the new repo file.

Answer (score 0):

Just a little thing: dump and load are ok. But I can't checkout the new repo created with `svnadmin create /NameOfNewRepo`

Comment: I try to do a checkout directly on the new server with  `file:///E:/SVN_Repositories/MyProjectDumped` and it's work. But it don't work with a client on the network and the `svn://AdressOfServer/E:/SVN_Repositories/MyProjectDumped` link. I check if the SVNserve service is ON and all is ok